# Execute Callback in Angular View?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a generic directive for tables that spits out some values based on some properties, for instance:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in table.data">
    <td ng-repeat="column in table.columns">
        <i ng-if="column.type === 'icon'" class="fa fa-{{column.icon}} fa-2x"></i>
        {{item[column.key]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The data structure might look like this:

```
$scope.table = {
    columns: [
        {key: 'flag', type: 'icon', icon: function (item) { return 'flag'; }},
        {key: 'acronym', type: 'desc', title: 'Acronym'},
    ],
    data: {}
};
```

As the directive loops through each item in the table data it creates a new table row. Each row follows the rules based on the column structure. In some situations there is an icon which is the same icon like an "arrow" and the `icon` will just be set to `arrow`. However sometimes the `icon` is dependent on values in the table `item` data. So I want to execute `icon` as a callback function in the view.

When I run something like {{column.icon(item)}} I get errors. Is there anyway to execute this callback from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `column.icon`, indeed a function for all your columns? If there is a column without this function, it will blow up. Make sure to add the icon method throughout.

```
$scope.table = {
    columns: [
        {key: 'flag', type: 'icon', icon: function (item) { return 'flag'; }},
        {key: 'acronym', type: 'desc', title: 'Acronym', icon: function (item) { return 'flag'; }},
    ],
    data: {}
};
```

Or first check to see if icon exists in the view before calling it.

```
{{column.icon && column.icon(item)}}
```

Comment: You're right, just had to preset all columns to have functions, thx.